# Diagonal discrimant analysis not available in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I´m trying to use the caret package to compare several discrimants models.

It turns out that the diagonal discriminant analysis is not working because of a missing dependency (method = 'dda')

```
 train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
                    method = "dda",
                    trControl = (method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3))
```

The missing package seems to be "sparsediscrim". Is this because other methods are much better (thinking of LDA) ?? Any idea ??

Thanks

Comment: without commenting on the models, when using caret you often need to download the dependencies separately.

Comment: Yes, that´s what i´m trying to do. It seems dda depends on package sparsediscrim. I can´t find it.
install.packages("sparsediscrim") will return package not found. Seems dependency is broken

Comment: Looks like it was archived see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparsediscrim/index.html

Comment: Oh yes , just recently archived. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. I have updated `sparsediscrim` to version 0.2.4 and updated on CRAN.

https://cran.r-project.org/package=sparsediscrim